# How to get specific instance in PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to get the specific value of file extension in this array. All I can do so far is .

I am wanting the fileextention **".jpg"**

All I know how to do is echo the values like so using foreach;

```
file_nameBob7213.jpg file_typeimage/jpeg
file_pathC:/xampp/htdocs/midas/records/
full_pathC:/xampp/htdocs/midas/records/Bob7213.jpg raw_nameBob7213
orig_nameBob72.jpg client_nameafasfafs.jpg **file_ext.jpg** file_size44.96
is_image1 image_width716 image_height474 image_typejpeg
image_size_strwidth="716" height="474"
```

I am only interested in retrieving the file_ext from this array. How do I select that exact thing?

```
foreach ($file['upload_data'] as $item => $value)
{
  echo $item; echo $value; echo "<br/>";
}
```

How do I do this? , thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$file['upload_data']['file_ext']
```

It's just an array within an array, so specify 2 array keys

Incidentally, if you want to see the contents of an array, a quick way of doing it is to use `var_export`:

```
var_export($file); # echoes the entire array
```

You don't need to write a foreach loop every time

Comment: For outputting an array for debugging purposes in a slightly more human-readable format, try `print_r($file);`.

Comment: @Chris: True enough. I'm just very used to typing var_export for some reason :)

Comment: I actually wasn't aware of it before, and it'd be nice to be able to copy-paste `array()`-formatted code in some cases, so thanks for bringing it to my attention!

Answer (score 0):

`$file['upload_data']['file_ext']` contains `'.jpg'`.